# How to check whether our web service is on or not in android?

Tags: android, web-services

I have a web service in Asp.net and I am accessing the web service in android via Ksoap library.

It is working fine when the server is on and my webservice mode is ON. The problem is that when the server is down or the web service is not on or in off mode it will show the exception of Connection timeout.

How to check whether my service is globally accessible or not on a button click?

Comment: Check whether the response (null or not), simple enough !!

Comment: Or a Status code i.e. 200 or 201

Comment: @Paresh Oh Yes! How can I forget about the getResponse(), thanks for reminding me again about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be using HttpResponse object to get result from web service, to check for result use this:

```
HttpResponse response;
// Your code to execute url in form of response = httpclient.execute(request)
..
if (resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
//Response is valid.
}else{
// Invalid response
}
```

Comment: This one is also useful! Thanks